# ¿Por que falla mi programa justo antes de finalizar?

Tags: c, matrices

Codifique este programa que consiste en leer 2 matrices de números enteros, sumar los valores que no pertenecen a la diagonal de cada matriz y al final determinar si dichos promedios son iguales o diferentes.

El caso es que una vez me entrega los resultados, y justo después de *"presionar cualquier tecla para finalizar"*, el programa deja de funcionar abruptamente. Ya probé cambiando el `system("pause")` por un `scanf` que lea un caracter y un número, pero en ninguno de los casos funcionó.

¿Alguien me podria decir que hay de malo en mi código?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
int mat[3][3][2], prom1 = 0,prom2 = 0,a,b,c; //En vez de utilizar dos matrices bidimensionales, utilicé una matriz tridimensional (para poder anidar todo en el mismo ciclo)
float num;

for (c = 1; c != 3;c++){
    printf("Por favor, ingrese numeros ENTEROS hasta llenar la matriz %i\n",c);
    for (a = 1 ;a != 4; a++){
        for(b = 1; b != 4 ; b++){
            do {
                scanf(" %f",&num);
                if (num != (int)num) puts("Asegurese de ingresar un numero ENTERO");
                }
            while (num != (int)num);
            mat[a][b][c] = (int)num;
            if (a != b){
                if(c == 1)
                    prom1 += mat[a][b][c];
                else
                    prom2 += mat[a][b][c];

                }
            }
        }
    }

if (prom1 / 6 == prom2 / 6) printf("Los promedios de los valores NO diagonales de ambas matrices es igual: %i\n",prom1/6);
else
    printf("El promedio de los valores NO DIAGONALES de ambas matrices es diferente \nMATRIZ1: %i\nMATRIZ2: %i\n",prom1/6,prom2/6);
system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Y te aparece algún error? por lo que veo.. tu programa despues de calcular los valores no hace mas nada... o mejor dicho hace lo normal... que es finalizar la ejecución... o no se si tal vez es que no has logrado que no se cierre la ventana inmediatamente y por lo tanto no alcanzas a ver los resultados...

Comment: Los arrays se indexan a partir del índice cero. Deberías recorrer tus bucles de la forma `for (c = 0; c < 3; c++)` y de manera análoga para los otros `for`.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Alguien me podria decir que hay de malo en mi código?

Para empezar, como te comenta @Xam, en C los índices empiezan en 0 (realmente un índice indica un desplazamiento sobre el primer elemento, es decir, es más un offset que un índice.

Así que los bucles deberías programarlos así:

```
for (c = 0; c != 2;c++){
    printf("Por favor, ingrese numeros ENTEROS hasta llenar la matriz %i\n",c);
    for (a = 0 ;a != 3; a++){
        for(b = 0; b != 3 ; b++){
```

Y con este pequeño cambio ya te debería funcionar... pero como preguntas sobre las cosas que están mal en tu código podemos continuar.

### Reduce la vida de las variables al mínimo

Desde C99 (estándar que data de 1999), se pueden declarar las variables en casi cualquier parte del programa (incluso dentro de los bucles). Reducir la vida de las variables al mínimo imprescindible es una buena idea ya que el programa pasa a ser más legible y reduce las posibilidades de meter la pata al reutilizar una variable:

```
for (int c = 0; c != 2;c++){
    printf("Por favor, ingrese numeros ENTEROS hasta llenar la matriz %i\n",c);
    for (int a = 0 ;a != 3; a++){
        for(int b = 0; b != 3 ; b++){
```

### Si solo te interesa leer enteros no uses float

```
scanf(" %f",&num);
if (num != (int)num) puts("Asegurese de ingresar un numero ENTERO");
```

Un problemilla asociado a los números decimales es que los mismos tienen una precisión máxima determinada que, en el caso de `float`, es de 6 dígitos. Esto quiere decir que a una variable de tipo `float` no se le va a dar demasiado bien almacenar el número 100.000.001 ya que dicho número excede los mencionados 6 dígitos de precisión.

Si el programa solo debe aceptar la entrada de números enteros entonces plantéate leer dichos números enteros y listo... o bien lees la entrada como una cadena de texto y verificas si dicha cadena es convertible completamente a un número entero.

¿Por qué te digo esto? Porque tu programa tal y como está no es infalible y para ello basta con que introduzcas una letra en cualquiera de las posiciones de la matriz y el programa se volverá loco.

Así que como no creo que ahora mismo te exijan validar la entrada del usuario ve a lo sencillo y no te compliques. Cambia esto:

```
do {
  scanf(" %f",&num);
  if (num != (int)num) puts("Asegurese de ingresar un numero ENTERO");
}
while (num != (int)num);
mat[a][b][c] = (int)num;
```

Por esto:

```
scanf(" %d",&mat[a][b][c]);
```

Es más corto, más limpio y va a funcionar igual de bien.

> Codifique este programa que consiste en leer 2 matrices de números enteros

Entonces esta definición para las matrices:

```
int mat[3][3][2]
```

No es precisamente la solución más limpia ya que en memoria estás mezclando los datos de ambas matrices (fila 0 de la primera matriz, fila 0 de la segunda matriz, fila 1 de la primera matriz, fila 1 de la segunda matriz, ...). Esta solución te va a impedir tratar cada matriz de forma independiente que si bien no es algo que te estén pidiendo ahora mismo te lo pedirán en un futuro próximo y mejor si vas adquiriendo buenas costumbres

Además, el comentario que incluyes:

```
//En vez de utilizar dos matrices bidimensionales, utilicé una matriz tridimensional (para poder anidar todo en el mismo ciclo)
```

No supone una justificación que se defienda demasiado bien.

Por un lado no te están diciendo que tengas que almacenar las matrices en ningún sitio... solo que almacenes un promedio de ciertos valores.

```
int main(){
  int promedio[2] = {0}; //En vez de utilizar dos matrices bidimensionales, utilicé una matriz tridimensional (para poder anidar todo en el mismo ciclo)

  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    printf("Por favor, ingrese numeros ENTEROS hasta llenar la matriz %i\n",i+1);
    for (int x = 0 ; x < 3; x++){
      for(int y = 0; y < 3 ; y++){
        int valor;
        scanf(" %d",&valor);
        if( x != y )
          promedio[i] += valor;
      }
    }
    promedio[i] /= 6;
  }
  
  if (promedio[0] == promedio[1])
    printf("Los promedios de los valores NO diagonales de ambas matrices es igual: %i\n",promedio[0]);
  else
    printf("El promedio de los valores NO DIAGONALES de ambas matrices es diferente \nMATRIZ1: %i\nMATRIZ2: %i\n",promedio[0],promedio[1]);
  return 0;
}
```